# How to move the Sphere using mouse in three.js? (Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined)

Tags: three.js

I was making a sphere that can be moved by a mouse using three.js but the output is just a black screen as shown.

[image: BlackScreen]

The code I used is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/kFoWvzw.jpg' );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );           
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.mouseButtons = {
                LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
                MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
                RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
            }
            controls.update();


            scene.add( sphere );



            function animate() 
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't explain why the code was unable to render the sphere. What went wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You could look at source code in [the official example](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit) to see how they do it. Keep in mind that Three.js is now on `revision 143`, and you're using `r79`, so the approach to import things has changed wildly since 2016.

Comment: @Marquizzo Ohh my, have I been using outdated three.js version R79 and the newest version if three.js is version R143? I must have mixed using the three.js versions R79 and R143 in a single HTML code...When I looked at the source code on your link, the code of OrbitControls.js is different from what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message indicates, you are trying to use `OrbitControls` but it cannot be found. This is because it is not part of the core THREE.js library, but it is in the THREE.js examples directory so you need to import it separately.

You can import it through an HTML script tag like you do with THREE.js:

`<script src="path/to/your/local/file/OrbitControls.js">`.

Notice also that if you import it in your HTML, you should call it as

`const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(...);`

as the `js/` file adds the class to the `THREE` object.

See [the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) or [the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js).

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I got the OrbitControls source, but it isn't still working. I still got the same error. What shall I do?

Comment: @Cambria Did you import it in your HTML? Also, you should probably call it as `THREE.OrbitControls()`.

Comment: I did, I changed the code into const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(...); but now the code outputs the error "Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor". But I think were going in the right direction because the original error has been fixed.

Comment: @Cambria Hmm. Could you show how you import it?

Comment: Sure!...I'll post the code in the answer....

Comment: @Cambria Looks like you're still not importing OrbitControls. You need to import e.g. this file: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: ahhh yes. That's the OrbitControls.js I have in my computer. I modified the code in my answer a bit in light of your suggestion. I have added the import command in the HTML code and I tried calling the OrbitControl.js by calling the link to the OrbitControl.js The next error would be: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module... I really thank you for guiding me for this one. I've been struggling in this for a week...hehehhe

Comment: @Cambria If you're using `import` in Javascript, then you need to include the script as a module `<script type="module">`. You can also just import the orbit controls in their own HTML `<script>` tag. I suggest you look into how to import things in javascript in general (make sure you check a **recent** guide as these things have changed a lot)

Comment: I now checked how to link the Javascript file to the HTML file via <script type="module"> and import command few minutes. I now modified the code again in light of your suggestion. The error Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module and Loading failed for the module with source “c:\Users\pc\Desktop\Lines\OrbitControls.js”, even if the OrbitControl.js file is housed in one folder.

Comment: I really thank you for helping and bearing up with me....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247180/discussion-between-berthur-and-cambria).

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code on how to move the camera on the Sphere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src=".\three.js-master\three.js-master\examples\js\controls\OrbitControls.js"></script> 
        <script>


            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
            

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/kFoWvzw.jpg' );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );           
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            

            controls.update();


            scene.add( sphere );



            function animate() 
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the correct code on how to move the camera on the Sphere...:-)